# osx: How to install a package into user's application support directory?

Tags: bash, macos, installation, pkgbuild

I need to install 2 audio plugins to the root Audio/Plug-Ins/VST & Components directories. My installer does that fine. But I also need to install a directory of preset files into /Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/MyCompany folder.

I've heard that an installer can't install to / and ~ in the same installer, but I really want it to be 1 install for the user. So it seems like a good idea would be to install the VST and Components first. Then install the preset folder in a temporary location (like /tmp or similar) and then run a post-install script to move the files to the user's Library...but I can't get that to work.

This is the script I'm trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

# movePresets.sh

# I want something like this...but it doesn't work because $USER is root in the installer I believe

/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER mkdir -p "/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/Presets"
/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER mv -r "/tmp/Presets" "$USER/$USER/Library/Application Support/MyCompany"


exit 0
```

Obviously, I don't know the proper way to access a user's directory as root. Help please...thank you.

Comment: You should create an installer package for this (eg. `.pkg`, `.mpkg`) using `productbuild`; it does everything you mentioned.

Comment: Where the post-install.sh file is gonna be? You could add that file to a location inside the user's home and then retrieve the user home path with it's location. Or simply you could require that the post-install file must be run from the user's home dir (which is the Terminal default directory when you launch it).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving off the user in a variable first?

```
#!/bin/bash
realuser=$USER
# or
#realuser=$(whoami)

/usr/bin/sudo -u $realuser mkdir -p "/Users/$realuser/Library/Application Support/MyCompany/Presets"
/usr/bin/sudo -u $realuser mv -r "/tmp/Presets" "$realuser/$realuser/Library/Application Support/MyCompany"
```

Comment: How is that different? $USER is still root, not the real user.